# How to make floor plan app using arkit in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I am beginner for Augmented reality type applications. I want to create an application which will detect corners of the room and after tapping on such corner points it will place objects there and create complete floor plan in 3D Using Augmented Reality.

I am able to see a default object also i am able to detect horizontal floor and place grid image over there till now.

My view controller from where i am detecting horizontal flow and placing grid image.

```
    import UIKit
    import SceneKit
    import ARKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!                 
        var planes = [ARPlaneAnchor: Plane]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            sceneView.delegate = self
            sceneView.showsStatistics = true
            sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
        }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
            configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
            sceneView.session.run(configuration)
        }

        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
            sceneView.session.pause()
        }

        // MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate            
        func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        }

        func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
        }

        func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
        }

        func addPlane(node: SCNNode, anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {
            let plane = Plane(anchor)
            planes[anchor] = plane
            node.addChildNode(plane)
        }

        func updatePlane(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {
            if let plane = planes[anchor] {
                plane.update(anchor)
            }
        }

        // MARK: - Add, Update, Remove Object Methods            
        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
                    self.addPlane(node: node, anchor: planeAnchor)
                }
            }
        }

        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
                    self.updatePlane(anchor: planeAnchor)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Node class**

```
class Plane: SCNNode {
    var planeAnchor: ARPlaneAnchor
    var planeGeometry: SCNPlane
    var planeNode: SCNNode

    init(_ anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {

        self.planeAnchor = anchor            
        let grid = UIImage(named: "plane_grid.png")
        self.planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(anchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(anchor.extent.z))
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = grid
        self.planeGeometry.materials = [material]            
        self.planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.transparency = 0.5
        self.planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
        self.planeNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2.0, 1, 0, 0)

        super.init()            
        self.addChildNode(planeNode)           
        self.position = SCNVector3(anchor.center.x, anchor.center.y, anchor.center.z) // 2 mm below the origin of plane.
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func update(_ anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {
        self.planeAnchor = anchor

        self.planeGeometry.width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
        self.planeGeometry.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)

        self.position = SCNVector3Make(anchor.center.x, anchor.center.y, anchor.center.z)
    }        
}
```

Now i want to detect corner and based on corners and doors i want to create complete floor plan in 3D in iOS.

Comment: Any updates on this ? I really wanted the same !!